# 100% document scale in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, ppi, scale

How can I setup actual 100% document scale in InDesign?

I'm working on a document for web and I need to everything as is. It looks like that InDesign calculates scale based on 72 PPI yet my monitor is 94 PPI. Thus the canvas is bigger than it's suppose to be.

In following example I've created the document is 800 px in width, but at 100% it is about 1044 px. That's correlated with my calculation with PPI: 94/72 * 800 px = 1044.4 px.

How can I setup a proper PPI so I can see 800 px document as exactly 800 px? In Photoshop everything works fine. Thanks.

[image: 800px document showed as 1044px]

Comment: You can’t, as far as I know. InDesign always uses 72 ppi when converting to pixels. Why does it matter, though? Just zoom out to 75% and it will match. It doesn’t matter what scale it is, anyway: different end users with different monitors with different pixel densities will all see the final result (PDF, I’m assuming) in different ways. What’s important is that the proportions are right.

Comment: I often use cmd+1 (ctrl+1) to view the canvas in 100%. Also, I want to see the pixel perfect result (I think it came from my past experience in Photoshop). If I set the 1 px stroke, then I want to see the sharp 1 px stroke at 100% (not 1.25 px or 0.98 px). I just don't understand why I can see the actual size in Photoshop and Illustrator (no matter what PPI), but I can't do that in InDesign...

Comment: Because Photoshop uses pixels internally as its native unit; InDesign uses points (which are derived from inches) and only approximates pixels (by multiplying the actual, physical size by the PPI). Cmd+1 shows you your artwork 1:1 in _print_ size. Pixels do not enter into the calculations at all there.

Comment: I found zoom settings, but in other program. Did someone seen something like this in InDesign: http://i.imgur.com/xuMOQA2.png

Comment: Please don't work on indesign for web, there are many features that are just not there and will make it a hell to convert to html/css